# Accessing database from local network

Tags: database, connection, local-area-network

I would like to access database running on virtual machine which resides in server connected to local network.
Here's the whole situation:
  There is Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter running as virtual machine and it has Oracle database on it. I'm using RDP to control OS remotely, but now I would like to use my computer to access database. I've tried creating database connection in JDeveloper with hostname just like my RDP connection IP, but unfortunately this way doesn't work.

Could anybody suggest the best way to accomplish such task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great answer for a very similar issue over on superuser.com at https://superuser.com/questions/130552/tunneling-a-tcp-ip-connection-through-remote-desktop-connection

Comment: The method suggested above will work if you can't expose the oracle server to the network via a public IP. However, depending on your circumstances simpler solutions might exist. Can you tell us more about your network setup, where the vm lives, etc.?